# Docker & PostgreSQL : can not create database having '-' in database name during initialization

Tags: database, docker, dockerfile, postgresql-9.4

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.4.6 in docker image with docker version 1.10.1. According to this official image:
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/443c7947d548b1c607e06f7a75ca475de7ff3284/9.4/Dockerfile
As it is said here , that to create initial databases I add my sql script in "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" .
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
Now after having some trouble I found that  when I add query to create a database in sql script where database name has '-' ,they just cause the container to crash(i.e. the containers exits just after starting).
But query with having no '-' in database name works fine and container also doesn't crash and i can access those database.
For example, This query runs fine.

```
create database 1stName_2ndName with owner vagrant;
```

But I tried both of this queries individually and it fails for both cases

```
create database '1stName-2ndName' with owner vagrant;
```

or

```
create database 1stName-2ndName with owner vagrant;
```

Note: consider queries without double-quotation. vagrant user is already created and works fine.

I have a database which name is 1stName-2ndName. Can anybody help me to figure out the issue?

Comment: When I add the sql query in the sql file ...where the database name has '-' (Hyphen) ..the docker container exits just after starting. But when I erase the '-' (Hyphen) from database name in the sql file ...then the container runs fine and I can access and see the databases inside container using docker exec. And actually the last two query are same . I just meant that ..I tried both ways. I will try to escape the DB name with " and `` and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my local Postgres installation, the following query works without a problem:

```
create database "1stName-2ndName" with owner vagrant;
```